# Ipad piano-like app help!

Tags: ipad, uibutton, draggable, sliding, piano

I am writing an iPad piano-like app. I firstly created the keys by UIButton, everything worked fine but when I want to slide from one key to another I found that it's a drag-out action (of the first button) rather than touch down action (of the second button) 
so Just wondering does anyone know any ways to disable the dragging of UIbutton or any other better way to do that sliding ?

Answer (score 0):

Very old question, but as I'm working on this now... When I started implementing a piano keyboard, I simply used a big image of the keyboard, and worked out what key was being pressed in my controllers `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved` methods.  Then, when I wanted to add key press effects, I thought `UIButton`s would work well.  Unfortunately, I ran into the same problem you have: the first `UIButton` key pressed "captures" the touch, which is then not available to the other keys.

The simplest solution, I think, is to go back to the original controller `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved` method.  I will change all my `UIButton`s into `UIImageView`s, and do touch detection and key animation from the controller.